# Stack overflow when calling math.randomseed(os.time())

Tags: lua

Ok, so I am writing a program in Lua that involves randomizing numbers, and it works fine... without `math.randomseed(os.time())`

When I add it, it causes a stack overflow at the line of `math.randomseed(os.time())`

My code is shown here:

```
local group1stregnths = 0
local group2stregnths = 0

function balancestregnths()
    math.randomseed(os.time())
    local assignedstrengths = math.random(1,6)

    if assignedstrengths == 1 then
        if group1stregnths == 2 then
            balancestregnths()
        end
        if group1stregnths < 2 then
            group1stregnths = group1stregnths + 1
        end
    end

    return assignedstrengths
end
```

And here's the overflow...

```
lua: Main.lua:17: stack overflow
stack traceback:
    Main.lua:17: in function 'balancestregnths'
```

Any help?

Comment: I added the code and the error!

Comment: I declared `randomseed` before the function, and it worked. If you could post your answer as an answer, I will gladly accept it! Thanks!

Comment: I took the liberty of reformatting your code. It's a *lot* easier to read with proper indentation and more judicious use of blank lines.

Comment: Thanks Keith, do you recommend any IDE's for Lua that do this automatically?

Comment: I hear zerobrane is pretty good.

Comment: Ok, ill look into it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not suppose to call `randomseed` more than once in a program. You keep resetting the seed everytime you call `balancestregnths` which means you keep getting the same 'random' sequence. That sequence causes a non-terminating recursive call.

Try moving `math.randomseed(os.time())` to the top of the script.